# Cómo llenar un arreglo de javascript con datos obtenidos de una consulta de sql server con c#

Tags: javascript, c#, sql-server, asp.net

Necesito saber como llenar un array de javascript con una consulta de sql server, lo que quiero lograr es que en un solo textbox me aparezcan los 3 elementos que tengo almacenados en una tabla de sql, pero al momento de ejecutar el programa solo me muestra un elemento en lugar de los 3, podrian ayudarme? Lo que estoy utilizando en c# es esto:

```
[WebMethod]
    public static string nuevo(int id) //select chido para equipos prestados
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        using (SqlConnection Conn = Conexion.conectar())
        {
            var jsonStr = "";
            using (SqlCommand cmdAc = new SqlCommand("pruebanahum1", Conn))
            {
                cmdAc.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmdAc.Parameters.Add("@IDPRESTAMO", SqlDbType.Int).Value = id;
                Conn.Open();
                using (SqlDataReader drInfoPrest1 = cmdAc.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (drInfoPrest1.Read())
                    {
                        InfoPrest2 PresInfo1 = new InfoPrest2();
                        PresInfo1.ID_EQUIPO = Convert.ToString(drInfoPrest1["ID_EQUIPO"]);
                        PresInfo1.DESCRIPCION = Convert.ToString(drInfoPrest1["DESCRIPCION"]);
                        JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
                        jsonStr = js.Serialize(PresInfo1);
                    }
                    drInfoPrest1.Close();
                    drInfoPrest1.Dispose();
                }
            }       
            Conn.Close();
            return jsonStr;
        }
    }
    public struct InfoPrest2 //estructura del sel equipos
    {
        public string ID_EQUIPO { get; set; }
        public string DESCRIPCION { get; set; }        
    }
```

Y en javascript utilizo esto:

```
function Imprimir(ctrl) {//trae la info. del accesorio

            var id = window.idglobal;
            console.log(id);
            var x = document.getElementById("bocinas");
            for (var i = 0; i < x.options.length; i++) {
var array = x[i].value;
            }
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'Proyector.aspx/nuevo',
                data: "{'id':'" + id + "'}",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert(jqXHR.responseText);
                },
                success: function (drInfoPrest1) {
                    // $('#aqui1').html(id_equipo1);
                    var jsonD = $.parseJSON(drInfoPrest1.d);
                    $('#s2id_bocinas').remove();
                    var exampleMulti = $("#bocinas").select2();
                    exampleMulti.val(jsonD.ID_EQUIPO).trigger("change");
                    var aber=[jsonD.ID_EQUIPO];
                    if (i == 1) {
                        uno = jsonD.ID_EQUIPO;
                        alert(array + "11111");
                    }
                    if (i == 2) {
                        dos = jsonD.ID_EQUIPO;
                        alert(array + "22222");
                    }
                    alert(jsonD.ID_EQUIPO + "sdff");
                    alert(dos + "sdff");
                }
            });
        }
```

Y mi consulta es esta:

```
select  dpe.ID_EQUIPO,ce.DESCRIPCION from DETALLE_PRESTAMO_EQUIPO as dpe
join CAT_EQUIPO as ce
on ce.ID_EQUIPO =dpe.ID_EQUIPO
where ID_PRESTAMO_CANON=@IDPRESTAMO
end
```

Comment: Podrias indicarme que error te esta dando

Comment: @RaulCacacho No me da errores, funciona a medias por así decirlo, lo que pasa es que solo me trae un solo elemento al txtbox en lugar de los 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que estás asignando solo un único elemento en `jsonStr = js.Serialize(PresInfo1);`, en tu caso el último.

---

Tendrías que modificar tu método web.

```
[WebMethod]
public static string nuevo(int id) //select chido para equipos prestados
{
    var listado = new List<InfoPrest2>();

    using (SqlConnection Conn = Conexion.conectar())
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmdAc = new SqlCommand("pruebanahum1", Conn))
        {
            cmdAc.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmdAc.Parameters.Add("@IDPRESTAMO", SqlDbType.Int).Value = id;
            Conn.Open();

            using (SqlDataReader drInfoPrest1 = cmdAc.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (drInfoPrest1.Read())
                {
                    listado.Add(new InfoPrest2{
                        ID_EQUIPO = drInfoPrest1["ID_EQUIPO"].ToString(),
                        DESCRIPCION = drInfoPrest1["DESCRIPCION"].ToString()
                    });
                }
            }
        }
    }

    var jsonStr = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(listado);

    return jsonStr;
}
```

Luego, para asignar los valores a tu selección múltiple:

```
function Imprimir(ctrl) {

    var id = window.idglobal;
    console.log(id);

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'Proyector.aspx/nuevo',
        data: "{'id':'" + id + "'}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(jqXHR.responseText);
        },
        success: function (drInfoPrest1) {
            $('#s2id_bocinas').remove();

            var $bocinasMulti = $("#bocinas").select2();
            var jsonD = $.parseJSON(drInfoPrest1.d);

            var valores = $.map(jsonD, function (el) {
                    return el.ID_EQUIPO
                });

            $bocinasMulti.val(valores);
            $bocinasMulti.trigger("change");
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias! Me funcionó :D

Comment: @AzaelOaryLópez no te olvides de dar la respuesta como aceptada :)

Answer (score 0):

Según lo que entiendo de tu caso, es que de la db quieres traer 3 valores y concatenarlos en un textbox. Bueno y por qué no lo haces directo de tu store procedure?

```
CONCAT (dpe.ID_EQUIPO, ce.DESCRIPCION)
```

o sino

```
(dpe.ID_EQUIPO + ' - ' +ce.DESCRIPCION) as texto
```

Aquí sólo veo dos campos, tal vez te estoy entendiendo mal.

Comment: No, por ejemplo, tengo 3 accesorios en la bd y cada uno tiene su id y una descripción, lo que quiero hacer es tomar las 3 id y guardarlas en un arreglo que después uso para llenar un txtbox y lo que tengo solo me trae una sola id al arreglo